Is it possible to inject a reference in a JSON schema?
I'm creating a JSON schema that has a definition called aggregated.
The aggregated object has the properties min, max, avg, and current.
Is it possible to inject a reference to a reference object to point it the the type of value that is sampled?
Current $defs
"$defs": {
  "temperature": {
    "type": "number",
    "description": "Temperature (°C)",
    "minimum": -273.15
  },
  "pH": {
    "type": "number",
    "description": "pH level",
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 14
  },
  "aggregated": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "min": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/temperature"
      },
      "max": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/temperature"
      },
      "avg": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/temperature"
      },
      "current": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/temperature"
      }
    }
  }
},

The aggregated definition is temperature aggregation, but how do I extend it to be either temperature aggregated or pH aggregated? This might seem simple but there are multiple types of allowed samples that goes in to the aggregated definition.
So later in my schema I would like to have something like this.
"measurements": {
  "temperature": {
    "$ref": "#/$defs/aggregated",
  },
}

But how would it look like if could inject a reference in the reference, somehow?
"measurements": {
  "temperature": {
    "$ref": "#/$defs/aggregated",
    "$dynamicRef": "#/$defs/temperature"
  },
  "pH": {
    "$ref": "#/$defs/aggregated",
    "$dynamicRef": "#/$defs/pH"
  }
}

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Sources of ideas that I've found so far
https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/dynamicref-and-generics
Is it possible to 'inject' reference to a JSON Schema
